# Swiftmailer not setting headers?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email with Swiftmailer but it doesn't seem to be setting the headers?
It sends ok, but the email never gets to its destination. When I look at my Mail Delivery Reports in CPanel the recipient is unknown. So I tried echoing the header and every thing is blank...

heres my code...

```
    echo "submitting email...";
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.example.com', 25)
    ->setUsername'username'
    ->setPassword('password');

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['attachedfile']['tmp_name'])
    ->setFilename($name.'_'.$email);

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Submission')
    ->setFrom(array('myemail@email.com' => 'my name'))
    ->setTo(array('youremail@gmail.com' => 'your name'))
    ->setBody('Name: ' . $name . '\nEmail: ' . $email . '\nDescription: ' . $descr)
    ->attach($attachment);


    $headers =  $message->getHeaders();
foreach ($headers->getAll() as $header) {
  printf("%s<br />\n", $header->getFieldName());
}

    $failedRecipients = array();
    $result = $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
if($result == 0) {
    echo "Failed sending email. Please try again later.<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Thanks for your submission!<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the attachment... I did it wrong. i was pointing to a non existent file... oops.